# How can I reset the value of the content of the selected select option whenever I choose another option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reset all the values of a, b and c whenever I select an option. The problem is that when I select 1 room and set the values for a, b, & c AND when select 2rooms or 3rooms the value of 1room a, b, & c when I select 1room again remains. All I want to see is, everytime I select rooms the previous room that I first selected should reset to zero. Any help?

To be clear I want to:

```
Selected option: 1 Room
Values of inputs : a=1, b=2, c=3
2 Rooms and 3Rooms values : a, b & c are = ZERO

When I select 2 Rooms
Values of inputs : a=1, b=2, c=3
1 Room and 3 Rooms values : a, b & c are = ZERO

When I select 3 Rooms
Values of inputs : a=1, b=2, c=3
1 Room and 2 Rooms values : a, b & c are = ZERO
```

[Live Code here](http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/2614/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset all your select elements by

```
$('#' + $(this).val()).find('select option').attr('selected', false);
```

```js
$(function() {
      $('#guest').change(function() {
        $('.rooms').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).find('select option').attr('selected', false);
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="guest">
  <option value="room1">1 Room</option>
  <option value="room2">2 Rooms</option>
  <option value="room3">3 Rooms</option>
</select>
<div class="rooms row-fluid col-md-12" id="room1">
  <!-- 1ROOM - -->
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- ROOM 1 -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p id="flight-label" class="col-xs-12">Room 1</p>
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Adult</option>
        <option value="one">1 Adult</option>
        <option value="two">2 Adults</option>
        <option value="three">3 Adults</option>
        <option value="four">4 Adults</option>
        <option value="five">5 Adults</option>
        <option value="six">6 Adults</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Adults</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Adults</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Adults</option>
        <option value="ten">10 Adults</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Child</option>
        <option value="one">1 Child</option>
        <option value="two">2 Children</option>
        <option value="three">3 Children</option>
        <option value="four">4 Children</option>
        <option value="five">5 Children</option>
        <option value="six">6 Children</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Children</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Children</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Children</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Infant</option>
        <option value="one">1 Infant</option>
        <option value="two">2 Infants</option>
        <option value="three">3 Infants</option>
        <option value="four">4 Infants</option>
        <option value="five">5 Infants</option>
        <option value="six">6 Infants</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Infants</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Infants</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Infants</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rooms row-fluid col-md-12" id="room2" style="display:none">
  <!-- 2ROOMS -->
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- Room1 -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p id="flight-label" class="col-xs-12">Room 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Adult</option>
        <option value="one">1 Adult</option>
        <option value="two">2 Adults</option>
        <option value="three">3 Adults</option>
        <option value="four">4 Adults</option>
        <option value="five">5 Adults</option>
        <option value="six">6 Adults</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Adults</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Adults</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Adults</option>
        <option value="ten">10 Adults</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Child</option>
        <option value="one">1 Child</option>
        <option value="two">2 Children</option>
        <option value="three">3 Children</option>
        <option value="four">4 Children</option>
        <option value="five">5 Children</option>
        <option value="six">6 Children</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Children</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Children</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Children</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Infant</option>
        <option value="one">1 Infant</option>
        <option value="two">2 Infants</option>
        <option value="three">3 Infants</option>
        <option value="four">4 Infants</option>
        <option value="five">5 Infants</option>
        <option value="six">6 Infants</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Infants</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Infants</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Infants</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- Room2 -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p id="flight-label" class="col-xs-12">Room 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Adult</option>
        <option value="one">1 Adult</option>
        <option value="two">2 Adults</option>
        <option value="three">3 Adults</option>
        <option value="four">4 Adults</option>
        <option value="five">5 Adults</option>
        <option value="six">6 Adults</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Adults</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Adults</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Adults</option>
        <option value="ten">10 Adults</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Child</option>
        <option value="one">1 Child</option>
        <option value="two">2 Children</option>
        <option value="three">3 Children</option>
        <option value="four">4 Children</option>
        <option value="five">5 Children</option>
        <option value="six">6 Children</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Children</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Children</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Children</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Infant</option>
        <option value="one">1 Infant</option>
        <option value="two">2 Infants</option>
        <option value="three">3 Infants</option>
        <option value="four">4 Infants</option>
        <option value="five">5 Infants</option>
        <option value="six">6 Infants</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Infants</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Infants</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Infants</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="rooms row-fluid col-md-12" id="room3" style="display:none">
  <!-- 3ROOMS -->
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- Room1 -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p id="flight-label" class="col-xs-12">Room 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Adult</option>
        <option value="one">1 Adult</option>
        <option value="two">2 Adults</option>
        <option value="three">3 Adults</option>
        <option value="four">4 Adults</option>
        <option value="five">5 Adults</option>
        <option value="six">6 Adults</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Adults</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Adults</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Adults</option>
        <option value="ten">10 Adults</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Child</option>
        <option value="one">1 Child</option>
        <option value="two">2 Children</option>
        <option value="three">3 Children</option>
        <option value="four">4 Children</option>
        <option value="five">5 Children</option>
        <option value="six">6 Children</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Children</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Children</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Children</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Infant</option>
        <option value="one">1 Infant</option>
        <option value="two">2 Infants</option>
        <option value="three">3 Infants</option>
        <option value="four">4 Infants</option>
        <option value="five">5 Infants</option>
        <option value="six">6 Infants</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Infants</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Infants</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Infants</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- Room2 -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p id="flight-label" class="col-xs-12">Room 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Adult</option>
        <option value="one">1 Adult</option>
        <option value="two">2 Adults</option>
        <option value="three">3 Adults</option>
        <option value="four">4 Adults</option>
        <option value="five">5 Adults</option>
        <option value="six">6 Adults</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Adults</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Adults</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Adults</option>
        <option value="ten">10 Adults</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Child</option>
        <option value="one">1 Child</option>
        <option value="two">2 Children</option>
        <option value="three">3 Children</option>
        <option value="four">4 Children</option>
        <option value="five">5 Children</option>
        <option value="six">6 Children</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Children</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Children</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Children</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Infant</option>
        <option value="one">1 Infant</option>
        <option value="two">2 Infants</option>
        <option value="three">3 Infants</option>
        <option value="four">4 Infants</option>
        <option value="five">5 Infants</option>
        <option value="six">6 Infants</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Infants</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Infants</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Infants</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <!-- 3rooms -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p id="flight-label" class="col-xs-12">Room 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Adult</option>
        <option value="one">1 Adult</option>
        <option value="two">2 Adults</option>
        <option value="three">3 Adults</option>
        <option value="four">4 Adults</option>
        <option value="five">5 Adults</option>
        <option value="six">6 Adults</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Adults</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Adults</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Adults</option>
        <option value="ten">10 Adults</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Child</option>
        <option value="one">1 Child</option>
        <option value="two">2 Children</option>
        <option value="three">3 Children</option>
        <option value="four">4 Children</option>
        <option value="five">5 Children</option>
        <option value="six">6 Children</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Children</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Children</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Children</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select class="form-control input-sm" id="form-tabs">
        <option value="zero">0 Infant</option>
        <option value="one">1 Infant</option>
        <option value="two">2 Infants</option>
        <option value="three">3 Infants</option>
        <option value="four">4 Infants</option>
        <option value="five">5 Infants</option>
        <option value="six">6 Infants</option>
        <option value="seven">7 Infants</option>
        <option value="eight">8 Infants</option>
        <option value="nine">9 Infants</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However you can still reduce the no. of HTML line by adding them *dynamically*.

<sup>**Note:**

Since you're using the jQuery v1.4.2 I have used [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) otherwise go with [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)</sup>